# How to run cron trigger with 5 sec exceeds process

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have developed a job which I want to run say after every 5 sec, but there may be certain circumstances where the job completion time may exceeds 5 sec.

My scenario: I want to start a job at 0.00 sec then 0.05, 0.10.. but my next job .15 sec takes exceed 5 sec to complete the job, so I want to skip .20 sec. I want to trigger next job at .25 sec.

```
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class).withIdentity("currentTime-Job-1", "group1").build();

Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("currentTime-Job-1", "group1")
        .startAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")).build();

sched.start();
sched.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);`
```

Comment: If you are looking for cron expression then check this out http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

The first is to change the interface used to declare the Job "Job 1" instead of Job uses "StatefulJob". But this kind is already deprecated.

The second is declare your class extending Job but including the following notations:

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class implements Job Job 1 {
// You code.
}
```

This ensures that the Job will run only once at the same time. Thus, if the time spent by the Job exceeds 5 seconds, the next time you run overlapping should be expected that is in progress (try again 5 seconds later).

Well, in response to your request for an example using annotations, I include one after.

Utilizo un proyecto Java basado en maven y mi entorno es:

```
Java 8 (1.8.0-92)
Eclipse 4.3.1
Quartz 2.2.1
```

Además, también incluyo loggin con:

```
log4j 1.2.17
slf4f 1.7.5
```

Archivo pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Torren-T</groupId>
  <artifactId>torren.t.es</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The main Java class is:

The main Java class is:

```
package torren.t.es;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.quartz.Job;

import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;

import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;


public class Terremoto {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Terremoto.class);

    private static Scheduler scheduler = null; 

    private Terremoto() {
    }

    private static final void dormirseNSegundos(int sleepingSeconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long)sleepingSeconds * (long)1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("I could not sleep");
            LOGGER.warn(e);
        }
    }

    private static final void go(Class<? extends Job> myJob) {
        JobDetail job;
        final String jobName = myJob.getName();
        final String trgName = jobName + "Trigger";
        final String grpName = jobName + "Group";


        // The Job.
        job = newJob(myJob).withIdentity(myJob.getName(), jobName).build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
              .withIdentity(trgName, grpName)
              .startNow()
                    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                      .withIntervalInSeconds(5)
                      .repeatForever())            
              .build();

        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
          try {
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed initialization job");
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
    }

    public static final void Start() {
        Start(-1, null);
    }

    public static final void Start(int sleepingSeconds) {
        Start(sleepingSeconds, null);
    }

    public static final void Start(Class<? extends Job> myJob) {
        Start(-1, myJob);
    }

    public static final void Start(int sleepingSeconds, Class<? extends Job> myJob) {
        try {
            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
            scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

            // and start
            scheduler.start();

            // Start job.
            if (myJob != null) {
                go(myJob);
            }

            // Going to sleep!
            if (0 < sleepingSeconds) {
                dormirseNSegundos(sleepingSeconds);
            }

            // Stop Scheduler.
            scheduler.shutdown();

        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed initialization scheduler");
            LOGGER.error(se);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Starting Scheduler ...");
        Start(60, TorrenTJob.class);
    }
}
```

The job class with annotations:

```
package torren.t.es;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.quartz.PersistJobDataAfterExecution;

@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TorrenTJob implements Job {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TorrenTJob.class);

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        LOGGER.info("Hello world from a TorrenTJob!");
    }
}
```

Console output I get is:

```
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  Terremoto:104 - Iniciando Scheduler ...
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1184 - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  SchedulerSignalerImpl:61 - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  QuartzScheduler:240 - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  RAMJobStore:155 - RAMJobStore initialized.
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  QuartzScheduler:305 - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'SchTorrenT' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 3 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1339 - Quartz scheduler 'SchTorrenT' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1343 - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  QuartzScheduler:575 - Scheduler SchTorrenT_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2016-05-08 11:23:28 INFO  TorrenTJob:17 - Hola mundo desde un Job
```

Comment: for example Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:12:50 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:12:57 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:13:01 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:13:06 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:13:10 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:13:15 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:13:20 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:13:26 IST 2016
Job1 --->>>hi here Time isSat May 07 12:13:32 IST 2016

Comment: how to use this code for CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))

Answer (score 0):

I think that really is working. I explain:

The Job must jump every 5 seconds, and this ensures the execution frequency established based on its first run:

```
07 May 2016 12:12:50 IST (first time and timebase for the rest).
07 May 2016 12:12:55 IST (do not get but two seconds later)
07 May 2016 12:13:00 IST (do not get but one second later)

...
```

And so for the rest.

What happens is that runs at regular times, ie, if it fails not try after 5 seconds, if not when you can, but always respects the defined range.

The truth is that I was confused, I dont really thought I'd try after 5 seconds, but according to the times set, it is not.

Comment: can you share any example code using those two annodation?

Comment: Yes, give me a little time and hit an example.

Although it is basically the same as you, unless right on the class declaration did lead it to these entries.

Well, wait and attachment.

Comment: hi @Ambarj2009 am waiting for your example

Comment: Yes, but i am busy. Is the life, please wait.